# MySQL Make it faster,add members count to family table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my code here that adds a sum of all members belongs to that profile. I did it in this way, I just want to know some alternative ways to make it faster.

I have here related tables  Municipality, Barangay, Purok, family_profile, family_members which orders their relationship.

```
    SELECT f.family_id,f.family_code,f.lname,f.fname,f.mname,f.exname,f.remark,p.*,b.*,m.*,
    (SELECT SUM(member_id!=0) from family_members WHERE family_id=f.family_id) AS MEMCOUNT
    from family_profile f
    LEFT join purok p on f.home_address=p.purok_id 
    LEFT join barangay b on p.brgy_id=b.brgy_id
    LEFT join municipality m on b.mun_id=m.mun_id
    where
    f.family_id!=0 AND
    family_code!='' 
    ORDER BY
    mun_name,brgy_name,purok_name,f.lname,f.fname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this query:

```
SELECT 
    f.family_id,
    f.family_code,
    f.lname,
    f.fname,
    f.mname,
    f.exname,
    f.remark,
    p.*,
    b.*,
    m.*,
    (
        SELECT SUM(member_id!=0) 
        FROM family_members 
        WHERE 
            family_id = f.family_id
    ) AS MEMCOUNT
FROM family_profile f
        LEFT JOIN purok p on f.home_address=p.purok_id 
        LEFT JOIN barangay b on p.brgy_id=b.brgy_id
        LEFT JOIN municipality m on b.mun_id=m.mun_id
WHERE
    f.family_id != 0 
AND family_code != '' 
ORDER BY
    mun_name,
    brgy_name,
    purok_name,
    f.lname,
    f.fname
```

You're calculating the SUM for each returned row. This is not optimised. The idea is to calculate it once only, by making it a recordset:

```
SELECT 
    f.family_id,
    f.family_code,
    f.lname,
    f.fname,
    f.mname,
    f.exname,
    f.remark,
    p.*,
    b.*,
    m.*,
    MEMCOUNT.cnt AS MEMCOUNT
FROM family_profile f
        LEFT JOIN purok p on f.home_address=p.purok_id 
        LEFT JOIN barangay b on p.brgy_id=b.brgy_id
        LEFT JOIN municipality m on b.mun_id=m.mun_id
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT family_id, SUM(member_id!=0) AS cnt
                FROM family_members 
                GROUP BY family_id
            ) AS MEMCOUNT ON MEMCOUNT.family_id = f.family_id
WHERE
    f.family_id != 0 
AND family_code != '' 
ORDER BY
    mun_name,
    brgy_name,
    purok_name,
    f.lname,
    f.fname
```

Comment: but don't forget, explain plans will tell us the real problems.

Comment: Yeah, just when I thought my query calculates every record. Thanks...I have tested it, its faster now..