# Laravel 5.2 optimize making leftjoin with sum() faster

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 5 tables which is related to a custom field which is string NOT the id.

I want to get the sum of the amount of each table related to the one I want to query.

> I manage to make it work using leftjoin but it takes at least 10 sec
>   to give results.

I want to **optimize** my query.

```
$raohs = Raoh::leftjoin('func','raoh.FFUNCCOD','=','func.FFUNCCOD')
            ->leftjoin('appd','raoh.FRAOCOD','=','appd.FRAOCOD')
            ->leftjoin('altd','raoh.FRAOCOD','=','altd.FRAOCOD')
            ->leftjoin('obrd','raoh.FRAOCOD','=','obrd.FRAOCOD')
            ->where(function($query) {
                $search = \Request::get('search');
                $query->where('fraodesc', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('fsourcod', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->where('func.FFUNCCOD', 'like', '%' . trim($ffunccod) . '%')
            ->select(\DB::raw('fraodesc,fsourcod,raoh.ffunccod,raoh.FRAOCOD,func.ffunction,sum(appd.FAMOUNT) AS fapprop, sum(altd.FAMOUNT) AS fallot, sum(obrd.FAMOUNT) AS foblig'))
            ->orderBy('ffunction')
            ->groupBy('raoh.FRAOCOD')
            ->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in my question i have loaded my query which is SUM() in every record,(making it slower). In order to make it faster, I only need to leftjoin sum() once in every table during the initialization. Heres how I did it.

I just remember i have similar question a long time ago here, with pure SQL only. [MySQL Make it faster,add members count to family table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900108/mysql-make-it-faster-add-members-count-to-family-table)

```
$raohs = Raoh::leftjoin('func','raoh.FFUNCCOD','=','func.FFUNCCOD')
            ->leftjoin(\DB::raw('(Select FRAOCOD, sum(FAMOUNT) as FAMOUNT from appd group by FRAOCOD) as appd'),'raoh.FRAOCOD','=','appd.FRAOCOD')
            ->leftjoin(\DB::raw('(Select FRAOCOD, sum(FAMOUNT) as FAMOUNT from altd group by FRAOCOD) as altd'),'raoh.FRAOCOD','=','altd.FRAOCOD')
            ->leftjoin(\DB::raw('(Select FRAOCOD, sum(FAMOUNT) as FAMOUNT from obrd group by FRAOCOD) as obrd'),'raoh.FRAOCOD','=','obrd.FRAOCOD')
            ->where(function($query) {
                $search = \Request::get('search');
                $query->where('fraodesc', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('fsourcod', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->where('func.FFUNCCOD', 'like', '%' . trim($ffunccod) . '%')
            ->select(\DB::raw('fraodesc,fsourcod,raoh.ffunccod, raoh.FRAOCOD, func.ffunction, appd.FAMOUNT as fapprop, altd.FAMOUNT as fallot, obrd.FAMOUNT as foblig'))
            ->orderBy('ffunction')
            ->groupBy('raoh.FRAOCOD')
            ->paginate(20);
```

> It query now in about a sec

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add indexes to the fields `raoh.FFUNCCOD` and `raoh.FRAOCOD`, just make sure you specify the index length long enough for values in these fields. E.g., if it's only 2 or 3 symbols long, specifying 3 (or more) is fine, but if it's long strings (10+ symbols), and you specify 3, it may become a problem. Particularly, joins may start working incorrectly.

If you add indexes using [Laravel's Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-indexes) though, you should be fine.

Let us know if adding these indexes gave any performance improvements. The problem also may be in the slow performance of your `LIKE` conditions.